# Building a filter on a collection

Tags: java

I must build a filter which, given some elements (Museum objects) returns only the ones which are from a specific room **and** a specific century. I  built before two functions: the first one applies a filter only on the room, and the second one only on the century and both correctly work (They put the objects which match correctly in an ArrayList called *filtrati*). This is my "third function" to reach the goal:

```
public Set < Pezzo > filtraSalaSecolo(String sala, int secolo)
        throws IOException {
    Set < Pezzo > filtrati = new HashSet();
    for (Iterator < Pezzo > i = parse().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Pezzo next = i.next();
        if (filtraSala(sala).contains(next) == true && filtraSecolo(
                secolo).contains(next) == true) {
            filtrati.add(next);
        }
    }
    return filtrati;
}
```

In this code `Pezzo` would be a data structure of the museum objects data. The code doesn't work well, because with the test (reported below) there's no output. I can't understand why.

```
public class FiltraSalaSecoloTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Filtri f = new Filtri();
        f.setFilePath(IFile.PATH_MUSEO);
        for (Iterator < Pezzo > i = f.filtraSalaSecolo(
                "Sala delle scienze moderne", 20).iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Pezzo next = i.next();
            System.out.println(next.getAnno() + "\t" + next.getSala());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but how do `filtraSala` and `filtraSecolo` work? And why do you call them again and again for each item? Can't you calculate `filtraSala(sala)` and the other list once and store the result in a variable? Why does the method throw an `IOException`? Do `filtraSala` and `filtraSecolo` operate on files? If they do, you should definitely cache the result.

Comment: Can you post your `parse()` function?. And how is `filtraSala` and `filtraSecolo` aware of the contents of `Pezzo next`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (guessing here, since the code was not given) that your `parse()` method *probably* is returning new objects each time, so when you attempt to filter, you are asking if the object from one `parse()` is contained in the set of objects from another `parse()`.  Unless you implement the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, the answer will always be no.

Instead, you need to parse once, and then filter the parsed results.  Ie)

```
public Set < Pezzo > filtraSalaSecolo(String sala, int secolo)
    throws IOException {
    Set < Pezzo > all = parse();
    Set < Pezzo > f1 = filtraSala(sala, all);
    Set < Pezzo > filtrati = filtraSecolo(secolo, f1);
    return filtrati;
}
```

And add a `Set<Pezzo>` argument to the `filtraSala` and `filtraSecolo` methods which is the set to be filtered.

Continuing the refactoring, `filtraSalaSecolo` should also have this extra argument, so it could be called as:

```
Set<Pezzo> filtrati = filtraSalaSecolo(sala, secolo, parse());
```